# Why jqGrid is very slow when number of rows displayed increases?

Tags: jqgrid

When I display a small amount per page, it's quick and very good. When I increase it to 100 or more it starts getting slow. At 1000 it's unbearable! This is the code used for drawing the grid:

```
 $("#stSearchTermsGrid").jqGrid({
        mtype: "POST",
        postData:{},
        datatype: function(postdata) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax/ajax_termsSearchGridSimple.php',
                data: postdata,
                async: false,
                dataType: "xml",
                error: function(){
                    alert('Error loading XML document');
                },
                success: function(data,stat,xmldata){
                    //check error
                    var $error=$(data).find('error').text();
                    if($error!="0")
                    {
                        messageBox("Error",$error);
                        return;
                    }
                    //content
                    var $content=$(data).find('content').text();
                    if($content!="0")
                    {
                        var thegrid = $("#stSearchTermsGrid")[0];
                        thegrid.addXmlData(xmldata.responseXML);
                    }
                }
            });
        },
        colNames:["tId","term", "revTerm", "uType","freq","description","fId","facet","modifiedTime"],
        colModel:[
            //tId
            {name:'tId',index:'tId',align:"center",searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','lt','le','gt','ge','in','ni']}},
            //term (editable)
            {name:'term',index:'term',searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','in','ni','bw','bn','ew','en','cn','nc']},editable:true,edittype:'text',editoptions:{size:20},editrules:{required:true},formoptions:{elmsuffix:'(*)'}},
            //revTerm (editable)
            {name:'revTerm',index:'revTerm',searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','in','ni','bw','bn','ew','en','cn','nc']},editable:true,edittype:'text',editoptions:{size:20},editrules:{required:true},formoptions:{elmsuffix:'(*)'}},
            //uType (editable)
            {name:'uType',index:'uType',align:"center",searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','in','ni']},editable:true,edittype:'select',editoptions:{value:{'':'any','NPU':'proper noun','NU':'noun','VU':'verb'}}},
            //freq
            {name:'freq',index:'freq',align:"center",searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','lt','le','gt','ge','in','ni']}},
            //description (editable)
            {name:'description',index:'description',searchoptions:{sopt:['bw','bn','ew','en','cn','nc']},editable:true,edittype:'textarea',editoptions:{rows:"3"}},
            //fId
            {name:'fId',index:'fId',align:"center",searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','lt','le','gt','ge','in','ni']}},
            //facet
            {name:'facet',index:'facet',searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','in','ni','bw','bn','ew','en','cn','nc']}},
            //modifiedTime
            {name:'modifiedTime',index:'modifiedTime',align:"center",searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','lt','le','gt','ge','bw','bn','ew','en','cn','nc']}}
        ],
        gridComplete: function(){
            var $ids=$("#stSearchTermsGrid").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
            for($i=0;$i<$ids.length;$i++){
                var $reference="<a href='javascript:void();' onclick=\"toGoogle('stSearchTermsGrid','"+$ids[$i]+"');\">G</a>";
                //update columns
                $("#stSearchTermsGrid").jqGrid('setRowData',$ids[$i],{"reference":$reference});

                //coloring the recently classified row
                var $colorRecentlyModified = '#DFFC91';
                var modifiedTime = $("#stSearchTermsGrid").jqGrid('getCell',$ids[$i],'modifiedTime');
                var timeDiff = Math.abs(new Date() - new Date(modifiedTime.replace(/-/g,'/')));
                // 86400000 is the number of milliseconds in one day. Multiplying by days to mark the ones which are modified a few days ago
                timeLimit = 86400000 * 1.5;
                if(timeDiff < timeLimit)
                {
                    for(colN=2; colN<9; colN++)
                        $("#stSearchTermsGrid").jqGrid('setCell', $ids[$i], colN, '', {'backgroundColor':$colorRecentlyModified});      
                }

                //coloring the unclassified row
                var $colorUnclassified = '#FFCECE';
                var $fId = $("#stSearchTermsGrid").jqGrid('getCell',$ids[$i],'fId');
                if($fId == "0")
                {
                    for(colN=2; colN<9; colN++)
                        $("#stSearchTermsGrid").jqGrid('setCell', $ids[$i], colN, '', {'backgroundColor':$colorUnclassified});    

                }

            }
        },
        sortable: true,
        //autowidth:true,
        width: 900, //width for grid
        height: 250, //height for grid
        sortname: 'term',    //default sort column
        caption: "Terms",    //caption for grid (empty will hide)
        hidegrid: false,
        gridview: true,        //load the grid more fast
        multiselect: true,    //support mulitselect
        //multiboxonly: true,
        pager: '#stSearchTermsGridPager',
        rowNum:10,
        rowList:[10,25,50,100,500,1000],
        viewrecords: true,    //show view record information
        viewsortcols: [true,'vertical',true], //show sortable column with icons
        editurl: 'ajax/ajax_termsEdit.php'
    });
    $("#stSearchTermsGrid").jqGrid('navGrid','#stSearchTermsGridPager',
        {edit:true,add:false,del:true,search:true,view:true,refresh:true}, 
        // edit options
        {    
            onclickSubmit : function(params, posdata) {
                var $tId=$("#stSearchTermsGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
                if($tId && $tId.length>0)
                {
                    var $rowAry=$("#stSearchTermsGrid").jqGrid('getRowData',$tId);
                    var $fId=$rowAry["fId"];
                    return {"fId":$fId}
                }
            },
            afterSubmit : gridAfterSubmit,
            reloadAfterSubmit: true,
            closeOnEscape:true,
            bottominfo:"Fields marked with (*) are required."
        },
        // add options
        {},
        //del options
        {
            msg: "Selected records(s) will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered.<br/> Are you sure?",
            afterSubmit : gridAfterSubmit,
            reloadAfterSubmit: true,
            closeOnEscape:true
        },
        // search options
        {multipleSearch:true,closeOnEscape:true},
        //view options
        {
            closeOnEscape:true
        }
    );
    $("#stSearchTermsGrid").jqGrid('gridResize',{minWidth:900,maxWidth:2000,minHeight:250, maxHeight:1000});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I see many places where the grid can be improved.

1) You should use **paging**. If you show the user 1000 rows of data, the data will be not displayed on the monitor **at once**. The user have to scroll the windows of web browser to see the most parts of data. Which sense has to spend time to paint the parts of window which will not be seen? The scrolling of data with respect of jqGrid is **much more effective** as scrolling of browser window. Moreover no person are able to analyse the 1000 rows of data. He have to change sorting and set different filters to understand which from the data are interesting for him. It is one more argument for the data paging and implemented some searching. It you already use advanced searching you can consider to use additionally [toolbar searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching) with the parameter `stringResult:true` which is compatible with the [advanced searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching).

2) you should **rewrite the code of `gridComplete` totally**. I suppose, that for relatively large number of rows the function is **the bottleneck** of your code. To verify this just temporary comment the function and compare the time of the grid painting. You should understand that every time you get data by id or set data by id jQuery will have to search the DOM element by id. Especially modification of data on the page can be very slow. By the way it seems to me that you set the same 'background-color' (what is 'backgroundColor' ???) CSS style for almost the whole cells of the rows. Why not set the 'background-color' for the row (`<tr>` element) instead?

3) I strictly recommend you not use `datatype` as function. Your server part should return some [error HTTP code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4). In the case the [loadError](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_events) event will work and you can decode and display the custom error message. All other in your data seems be standard and you need not use `datatype` as function. If you will use `datatype:"xml"` you can for example try to use `loadonce:true` and implement client-side data paging and sorting if you will have problem with implementation of this features on the server.

I don't want to write too long text so I stop on the 3 most important points. By the way if you will switch from XML to JSON as the datatype used for the communication with the server, it will also improve a little the performance.

**UPDATED:** To see the performance of jqGrid with 1000 rows of data [without paging](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/1000.htm) and [with data paging](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/1000paged.htm) look at the links. Is by the way the performance of my example with 1000 rows without paging also so slow as in your case?

Comment: @Ahmad Farid: I suppose you vote down my answer. It is interesting for me to know the reason of this. I mean the rule described in http://stackoverflow.com/faq#behonest.

Comment: @Oleg: I pulled down your test page "without paging" and changed it to produce 5000 rows, set a height of 500px and set hoverrows to true. When scrolling each scroll event is delayed. In IE 11 the time it took to render the page was also significantly slower to render compared to Chrome. Any ideas what causes these issues?

Comment: @JimScott: I'm not sure that I understand you correctly. Do you use something like [the following](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/5000__height.htm)? It's clear that Chrome is the best (the most quick in JavaScript and rendering) web browser. IE (IE11 too) is slowly. By the way if you use scroll rad for scrolling IE will be not so slow. Nevertheless where you see any problem? Why you don't use local paging? If you for example change in the page the number of rows to `20` or `100` all will be quickly in all browsers.

Comment: @Oleg: I went to the link you provided and get the same exact behavior I described using IE 11. I go to the page and can see two issues that we found. 1) As you move your mouse over each row it is supposed to show a highlight which it does, however if you move your mouse down several rows it takes forever for the hover to catch up and will highlight each row you paused over till it catches up to your mouse position. 2) If you scroll it takes a few seconds between each scroll event.

Comment: @JimScott: Sorry, but I'm not sure what is your goals. We can't change the code of IE installed at our customers. It's better to write our code so that the page works quickly. I recommended in my answer to use **local paging** which allows to hold locally thousands of rows and jqGrid will still work very quickly. Why you don't follow the advise? What is your goal?

Comment: @Oleg I have same issue as jim. I have jqgrid with 3000 rows displayed and height is fixed to 200px. so now when i scroll, each scroll event takes few seconds to take effects. my goal is to do smooth scroll like it works with 10 items. any suggestions ? my jqgrid version is 5.2 (latest)

Comment: @Hayat: It's difficult to help you having only **the description** of your program instead of the code.First of all "jqGrid" exist only till the version 4.7 published at the end of 2014. After that there are two main forks: **commercial** "Guriddo jqGrid JS" available for [the price](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) and ["free jqGrid"](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), which I develop. The latest version of "Guriddo jqGrid JS" is 5.2.1. The latest version of "free jqGrid" is 4.14.1. I use 4.x.y naming conversion because I try to hold maximal compatibility to old 4.x versions of jqGrid

Comment: @Hayat: Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-5000-25-free-jqgrid.htm), which display 5000 rows, 13 columns in pages with 25 rows. Try the performance of paging, sorting and filtering. You can try [another demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-15-60000-25-free-jqgrid.htm), which display 60000 rows. You can test the performance. I don't recommend to use virtual scrolling (`scroll: 1`), which has many problems. The standard paging is quickly and intuitive for the users.

Comment: @Oleg yes you are right, I have purchased licence version of jQgrid 5.2 trirand. i got the issue with my grid. I had one assigned object to each row of approx json of size 400kb. so overall performance is going down. thanks for quick reply.

Comment: @Hayat: You are welcome! In general you should decide which one jqGrid fork to use. You can buy Guriddo jqGrid JS and get support from Tony Tomov or you can use free jqGrid fork, which I develop and which is available under old MIT or GPLv2 licenses completely free of charge. Both forks of jqGrid are based on jqGrid 4.7, but both contains many new features. You can see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/compare/v4.7.0...master) that I made more as 1600 commits (and much more that that changes) after v4.7. **I can help you only with "free jqGrid" and not with Guriddo jqGrid JS.**