# jqGrid slow loading data from ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jqgrid

I've a jqGrid loading some data.

I've good performance up to 15 registers. When I receive more than 15 registers, the loading time increase 20 - 30 - 40 seconds.

The data from the server arrives in 2 or 3 seconds, and after that I think that jqgrid spends all the time just loading data. Data is coming from ajax and I generate it using php and json encode.

Here is my code. I've tried with grdview:true, but the time is the same. I've tried without formatters and using plain data, and the time is the same. I need some help.

Thanks

```
    <script> 
$(function() {
    $( "[title]" ).tooltip({});     
    var onoff='off';
    //tabla listado de tareas

    jQuery("#task_list_una").jqGrid
    ({

    url:'json/avisos_wl_tasklist_json.php?tipo=una&new_call=<?=$_GET[CALL_ID]?>&rango_fechas=<?= $_GET[rango_fechas]?>&product_line=<?= $_POST[product_line]?>&user_actual=<?= $_POST[user_actual]?>&fecha_ini=<?= $date_from?>&ver_borrados=<?= $_GET[ver_borrados]?>&search_customer=<?= $_POST[search_customer_code]?>&search_serial=<?= $_POST[search_serial]?>',
    datatype: "json",   
    colNames:['','<?= lang("CALL_ID"); ?>','<?= lang("CALL_DATE"); ?>', '<?= lang("CALL_TIME"); ?>', '<?= lang("STATUS"); ?>','<?= lang("PRODUCT_LINE"); ?>','<?= lang("PRODUCT_FAMILY"); ?>','<?= lang("USER_CREADOR"); ?>','<?= lang("CUSTOMER_CODE"); ?>','<?= lang("CUSTOMER_NAME"); ?>','<?= lang("DEPARTAMENTO"); ?>','<?= lang("TELF_PRIN"); ?>','<?= lang("TELF_MOVIL"); ?>','<?= lang("CONT_NOMBRE"); ?>','<?= lang("AVISO_ST"); ?>','<?= lang("EMAIL"); ?>','','','','','','','',''],
    colModel:[
        {name:'title_resumen',index:'title_resumen',hidden:true},
        {name:'CALL_ID',index:'CALL_ID', width:30, align:"center",sorttype:"int", formatter:new_call_unaFormat, title:false},
        {name:'CALL_DATE',index:'CALL_DATE', width:30, align:"center",sorttype:"date", formatter:new_call_unaFormat, title:false, searchoptions:{defaultValue:'<?= $_SESSION["login_user"]->BUSQUEDA_TASK_LIST[CALL_DATE]?>'}},
        {name:'hora',index:'CALL_TIME', width:20, align:"center", formatter:new_call_unaFormat, title:false, searchoptions:{defaultValue:'<?= $_SESSION["login_user"]->BUSQUEDA_TASK_LIST[CALL_TIME]?>'}},
        {name:'estado',index:'CAMPO05', width:25, align:"center", formatter:estado_unaFormat, title:false, searchoptions:{defaultValue:'<?= $_SESSION["login_user"]->BUSQUEDA_TASK_LIST[CAMPO05]?>'}},
        {name:'linea',index:'CAMPO17', width:15, align:"center", formatter:new_call_unaFormat, title:false, searchoptions:{defaultValue:'<?= $_SESSION["login_user"]->BUSQUEDA_TASK_LIST[CAMPO17]?>'}},
        {name:'producto',index:'CAMPO07', width:25, align:"center", formatter:new_call_unaFormat, title:false, searchoptions:{defaultValue:'<?= $_SESSION["login_user"]->BUSQUEDA_TASK_LIST[CAMPO07]?>'}},  
        {name:'CAMPO29',index:'CAMPO29', width:35, align:"center", formatter:new_call_unaFormat, title:false, searchoptions:{defaultValue:'<?= $_SESSION["login_user"]->BUSQUEDA_TASK_LIST[CAMPO29]?>'}},   
        {name:'codigo_cliente',index:'CUSTOMER_CODE', width:25 , align:"center", formatter:new_call_unaFormat, title:false, searchoptions:{defaultValue:'<?= $_SESSION["login_user"]->BUSQUEDA_TASK_LIST[CUSTOMER_CODE]?>'}},
        {name:'nombre_cliente',index:'CUSTOMER_NAME', width:75 , align:"center", title:false, formatter:nombre_cliente_unaFormat, searchoptions:{defaultValue:'<?= $_SESSION["login_user"]->BUSQUEDA_TASK_LIST[CUSTOMER_NAME]?>'}},
        {name:'departamento',index:'DEPARTAMENTO', width:75 , formatter:new_call_unaFormat, align:"center", searchoptions:{defaultValue:'<?= $_SESSION["login_user"]->BUSQUEDA_TASK_LIST[DEPARTAMENTO]?>'}},
        {name:'telefono1',index:'TELF_PRIN', width:35 , formatter:telefono1Format, align:"center", searchoptions:{defaultValue:'<?= $_SESSION["login_user"]->BUSQUEDA_TASK_LIST[TELF_PRIN]?>'}},
        {name:'telefono2',index:'TELF_MOVIL', width:35 , formatter:telefono2Format, align:"center", searchoptions:{defaultValue:'<?= $_SESSION["login_user"]->BUSQUEDA_TASK_LIST[TELF_MOVIL]?>'}},
        {name:'nombre_contacto',index:'CONT_NOMBRE', width:50, formatter:new_call_unaFormat, align:"center", searchoptions:{defaultValue:'<?= $_SESSION["login_user"]->BUSQUEDA_TASK_LIST[CONT_NOMBRE]?>'}},
        {name:'aviso_st',index:'AVISO_ST', width:35 , formatter:new_call_unaFormat, align:"center", searchoptions:{defaultValue:'<?= $_SESSION["login_user"]->BUSQUEDA_TASK_LIST[AVISO_ST]?>'}},
        {name:'log_mail',index:'log_mail', width:15, align:"center"},   
        {name:'index_resumen_altalt',index:'index_resumen_altalt',hidden:true},
        {name:'title_nombre_cliente',index:'title_nombre_cliente',hidden:true},
        {name:'color_new_call',index:'color_new_call',hidden:true},
        {name:'color_estado',index:'color_estado',hidden:true},
        {name:'telefono1_sincolor',index:'telefono1_sincolor',hidden:true},
        {name:'telefono2_sincolor',index:'telefono2_sincolor',hidden:true},
        {name:'popup',index:'popup',hidden:true},        
        {name:'popup2',index:'popup2',hidden:true},                 
        ],  
    toolbarfilter:true,
    navigator:true,
    search:false,
    rowNum:-1,
    pager: '#task_list_una_pager',
    pgbuttons: false,           // disable page control like next, back button
    pgtext: null,               // disable pager text like 'Page 0 of 10'
    sortname: 'CALL_ID',        //poner index para ordenar
    viewrecords: true,          
    sortorder: "desc",
    caption:"<?= lang("TAREA");?>",
    height:'540',
    width:'1480',
    exporfile: 'texto.xls',
    altRows:true,                       //para pijama
    altclass:'myAltRowClass',           //color pijama css
    scrollrows:true,
    gridview: true,
    gridComplete: function()
                    {
                        $("[title]").tooltip({});
                        if (<?= $_GET[rowidjqgrid]?>+15>$("#task_list_una").getGridParam("reccount"))
                        {       
                        $("#task_list_una").jqGrid('setSelection',<?= $_GET[rowidjqgrid]?>);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        $("#task_list_una").jqGrid('setSelection',<?= $_GET[rowidjqgrid]?>+15);                         
                        }
                        $("#task_list_una").jqGrid('resetSelection');
                    }
    });
    jQuery("#task_list_una").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{searchOnEnter : false});

    jQuery("#task_list_una").jqGrid('navGrid','#task_list_una_pager',{"edit": false,"add": false,"del": false,"search": true,"refresh": false,"view": true,"excel": true,"columns": false},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {multipleSearch:false},
            {
                beforeShowForm: function(form) 
                {           
                    var dlgDiv = $("#viewmod" + $("#task_list_una")[0].id);
                    var parentDiv = dlgDiv.parent();
                    var dlgWidth = dlgDiv.width();
                    var parentWidth = parentDiv.width();
                    var dlgHeight = dlgDiv.height();
                    var parentHeight = parentDiv.height();
                    var parentTop = parentDiv.offset().top;
                    var parentLeft = parentDiv.offset().left;
                    dlgDiv[0].style.top =  Math.round(  parentTop  + (parentHeight-dlgHeight)/2  +100) + "px";
                    dlgDiv[0].style.left = Math.round(  parentLeft + (parentWidth-dlgWidth  )/2 )  + "px";
                }
            }
            );

    jQuery("#task_list_una").jqGrid('navButtonAdd','#task_list_una_pager',{
           caption:"",
           onClickButton: function () {
               jQuery("#task_list_una").jqGrid('excelExport', {url: 'json/avisos_wl_tasklist_exportxls.php?tipo=una&new_call=<?=$_GET[CALL_ID]?>&rango_fechas=<?= $_GET[rango_fechas]?>&product_line=<?= $_POST[product_line]?>&user_actual=<?= $_POST[user_actual]?>&fecha_ini=<?= $date_from?>&fuera=<?= $_POST[fuera]?>&ver_borrados=<?= $_GET[ver_borrados]?>&search_customer=<?= $_POST[search_customer_code]?>&search_serial=<?= $_POST[search_serial]?>'});
            },
            position: "last",
            buttonicon: "ui-icon-extlink"});


    jQuery("#task_list_una").jqGrid('navButtonAdd','#task_list_una_pager',{
           caption:"",
           title:"Clear filters",
           onClickButton: function () {
               jQuery("#task_list_una").jqGrid('setGridParam', { search: false, postData: { "filters": ""} }).trigger("reloadGrid");
               $("form[name='refresh']").submit();
            },
            position: "last",
            buttonicon: "ui-icon-refresh"});



});

</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: could be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969322/why-jqgrid-is-very-slow-when-number-of-rows-displayed-increases

Comment: I've already read it... I have problems with more than 15 and I don't want to show more than 200.I don't want to use pagination, because it is a task list of the day. I don't have gridcomplete work, just the position of the selected row, because I lost the position if the row is not in the first "page".